# PHP chatbox with existing user session

Tags: php

So I've searched high and low for this and found nothing I could really use... 
I work on a website mainly based on PHP and I would like to put a chatbox function there. Our members already sign in on a different page and it would be great if the chatbox would pull that session rather than ask for another log in or anything.

Also, I would like to implement different chatboxes according to a specification of the members (predefined groups can chat to each other, defined by a database entry)

If it could also be php that would be amazing! I've tried a certain chatbox, but it didn't seem to work...

I am still learning and I would love it to be quite customizable with images and backgrounds etc... any help and guidance and I would honestly love you forever!

Comment: you can use http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/ in your webpage

Answer (score 0):

You could load the new messages for example with an AJAX-Request that specifies the chat-room and the last-seen-message as a POST or GET-Parameter. In the script your existing Session could be easily accessed. The answer could be formatted as JSON. JSON is very easy to parse on the JavaScript-side.

Now just add an interval (`setInterval()`) that periodically checks for new messages and you are finished with a very simple chatbox.

For saving you can use either a Text-File or a database. The second one would be probably easier, but you'll need more optimizations there to not-kill your server.

Comment: I've written a chat myself, but this is probably not usething useful for you. I don't know any standalone shout-/chatboxes.

Answer (score 0):

For this chatbox, as with any component, the decision between using a customized out-of-the box one or roll your own is largely down to which is more work. Since your login and chatgroup requirements look like an awful lot of work (resulting in an awful mess) when force-customized onto an existing chatbox, I'd advise to roll your own.

Some hints:

- Use long polling for the clients, this tends to be robust and often is an acceptable balance between concurrent connection count and CPU use.
- Make sure to transmit your server timestamp with every reply.
- Use a simple DB table for your chats with the timestamp as a primary key. The query cache will do 90% of your work

Comment: That depends on your server, the number of clients, and - most important, your implementation. Sane implementations end the longest running polls when connection count goes above a threshold and have something like a 200-500ms delay on repoll at the client end. This flattens connection count peaks rather effectively